# c# linq to xml query help

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, xelement

Lets assume a xml file named data.xml with following content:

```
<root>
<record>
<id>1</id>
<name>test 1</name>
<resume>this is the resume</resume>
<specs>these are the specs</specs>
</record>
<record>
<id>2</id>
<name>test 2</name>
<resume>this is the resume 2</resume>
</record>
<record>
<id>3</id>
<name>test 3</name>
<specs>these are the specs 3</specs>
</record>
</root>
```

I need to search all records where any of these fields (id, name, resume or specs) contains a given value. I've created this code

```
XDocument DOC = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
IEnumerable<ProductRecord> results = from obj in DOC.Descendants("record")
     where 
obj.Element("id").Value.Contains(valueToSearch) ||
obj.Element("name").Value.Contains(valueToSearch) ||
obj.Element("resume").Value.Contains(valueToSearch) ||
obj.Element("specs").Value.Contains(valueToSearch)
     select new ProductRecord {
ID = obj.Element("id").Value,
Name = obj.Element("name").Value,
Resume = obj.Element("resume").Value,
Specs = obj.Element("specs").Value
     };
```

This code throws an error of NullReference since not all records have all fields. 
How can i test if current record has a given element before i define a condition to apply? Ex. Record[@ID=3] has no resume.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an extension method which is like bellow:

```
public static class XMLExtension
{
    public static string GetValue(this XElement input)
    {
        if (input != null)
            return input.Value;
        return null;
    }

    public static bool XMLContains(this string input, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return false;
        return input.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

and use it as below:

```
IEnumerable<ProductRecord> results = from obj in DOC.Descendants("record")
                                                 where
                                            obj.Element("id").GetValue().XMLContains(valueToSearch) || ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullReferenceException because you are trying to access the value of some nodes that don't exist for each `record` like `specs`. You need to check whether `obj.Element("specs") != null` before calling `.Value` on it.

As an alternative you could use XPath:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var records = doc.XPathSelectElements("//record[contains(id, '2') or contains(name, 'test') or contains(resume, 'res') or contains(specs, 'spe')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'm amazed that it's not crashing because you're not using the Namespace. Maybe c#4.0 has bypassed this?

Anyway try

```
obj.Descendants("id").Any() ? root.Element("id").Value : null
```

That is:

```
select new ProductRecord {
    ID = obj.Descendants("id").Any() ? root.Element("id").Value : null,
    Name = obj.Descendants("name").Any() ? root.Element("name").Value : null,
    Resume = obj.Descendants("resume").Any() ? root.Element("resume").Value : null
    Specs = obj.Descendants("specs").Any() ? root.Element("specs").Value : null
};
```

Comment: the problem is NOT in select, i bypassed this with this code Specs = (string)obj.Element("Specs") ?? "n/a". The main problem is in where clause...

Comment: Try using the same logic? (string)obj.Element("Specs") ?? true. As if if the object doesn't exist you wish to take it as a true option for that record.